# fileinput.hook_compressed gives me strings sometimes, bytes other times

Tags: python, file, python-3.8

I'm trying to read lines from a number of files. Some are gzipped, and others are plain text files. In Python 2.7, I have been using the following code and it worked:

```
for line in fileinput.input(filenames, openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed):
    match = REGEX.match(line)
    if (match):
        # do things with line...
```

Now I moved to Python 3.8, and it still works ok with plain text files, but when it encounters gzipped files I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

What's the best way to fix this? I know I can check if `line` is a bytes object and decode it into a string, but I would rather do it with some flag to automatically always iterate lines as string, if possible; and, I would prefer to write code that works with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Have you tried `mode='rt'`?

Comment: @HeapOverflow. Unfortunately, "[mode] must be one of 'r', 'rU', 'U' and 'rb'."

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ah. I only looked at the options for `open` and `gzip.open`. Pity. I guess they'll have to write their own hook...

Comment: Thanks but, if I have to write my own hook, then what use is fileinput.hook_compressed?

Comment: @k314159. Hang on for a bit. I'm coming up with an answer

Comment: I'm wondering why this isn't returning strings already, according to what I've read, `fileinput.input` should be using `mode='r'` by default (overriding the default `'rb'` of `gzip`).

Comment: @mkrieger1. when you pass `r` to gzip it defaults to binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fileinput.input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) does fundamentally different things depending on whether it gets a gzipped file or not. For text files, it opens with regular [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), which effectively opens in text mode by default. For [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open), the default mode is binary, which is sensible for compressed files of unknown content.

The binary-only restriction is artificially imposed by [`fileinput.FileInput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput). From the code of the [`__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/fileinput.py#L211) method:

> ```
>   # restrict mode argument to reading modes
>    if mode not in ('r', 'rU', 'U', 'rb'):
>        raise ValueError("FileInput opening mode must be one of "
>                         "'r', 'rU', 'U' and 'rb'")
>    if 'U' in mode:
>        import warnings
>        warnings.warn("'U' mode is deprecated",
>                      DeprecationWarning, 2)
>    self._mode = mode
> ```

This gives you two options for a workaround.

**Option 1**

Set the `_mode` attribute after `__init__`. To avoid adding extra lines of code to your usage, you can subclass `fileinput.FileInput` and use the class directly:

```
class TextFileInput(fileinput.FileInput):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'mode' in kwargs and 't' in kwargs['mode']:
            mode = kwargs.pop['mode']
        else:
            mode = ''
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if mode:
            self._mode = mode

for line in TextFileInput(filenames, openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed, mode='rt'):
    ...
```

**Option 2**

Messing with undocumented leading-underscore is pretty hacky, so instead, you can create a custom hook for zip files. This is actually pretty easy, since you can use the code for [`fileinput.hook_compressed`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/fileinput.py#L395) as a template:

```
def my_hook_compressed(filename, mode):
    if 'b' not in mode:
        mode += 't'
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if ext == '.gz':
        import gzip
        return gzip.open(filename, mode)
    elif ext == '.bz2':
        import bz2
        return bz2.open(filename, mode)
    else:
        return open(filename, mode)
```

**Option 3**

Finally, you can always decode your bytes to unicode strings. This is clearly not the preferable option.

Comment: Thanks. However, the documentation for [bz2.BZ2File](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2File) does not mention that text mode is allowed; on the other hand, [bz2.open](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/bz2.html#bz2.open) _does_, so maybe your answer should using bz2.open instead. But either way, this only works in Python 3.8 as Python 2.7 doesn't allow "t" as a mode (either for bz2 or gzip). So I would have to check sys.version, and if it's 2, use fileinput.hook_compressed, otherwise use my_hook_compressed - which is a bit hacky.

Comment: @k314159. Unfortunately, there are irreconcilable differences between python 2 and 3, including the encoding and decoding of strings. I have fixed the call to `bz2.open`, since your arguments is correct in that regard. The original code was a direct copy of the implementation in the source code with a single `if` statement added. The goal is not to provide a production-worthy implementation here, but just to illustrate some options.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, should Option 1 say `for line in TextFileInput(filenames, mode='rt', openhook=fileinput.hook_compressed):`?

Comment: @k314159. Yes. And now it does. Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer by [Mad Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist) to include `xz` and `zst` extensions.

```py
def my_hook_compressed(filename, mode):
    """hook for fileinput so we can also handle compressed files seamlessly"""
    if 'b' not in mode:
        mode += 't'
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if ext == '.gz':
        import gzip
        return gzip.open(filename, mode)
    elif ext == '.bz2':
        import bz2
        return bz2.open(filename, mode)
    elif ext == '.xz':
        import lzma
        return lzma.open(filename, mode)
    elif ext == '.zst':
        import zstandard, io
        compressed = open(filename, 'rb')
        decompressor = zstandard.ZstdDecompressor()
        stream_reader = decompressor.stream_reader(compressed)
        return io.TextIOWrapper(stream_reader)
    else:
        return open(filename, mode)
```

I have not tested on 2.7, but this works with 3.8+

```py
for line in fileinput.input(filenames, openhook=my_hook_compressed):
    ...
```